# toggleClass to switch pages gives white flash between

Tags: jquery, css

I have a single page app, each page is set to display:none.

to show pages, I add a class to them:

```
.current-page{
    display:block;
}
```

so to switch pages, I simply toggleClass('current-page') between my current-page and the page I want to switch to:

```
$('.current-page, #'+desiredPage).toggleClass('current-page')
```

However, this doesn't seem to happen instantly, I get a white flash between pages, as if there is a split second delay between one page being hidden and the other being displayed.

What's the best way to get round this? is there a better way to switch pages?

Comment: Are you loading them dynamically with ajax ? Could you show us a jsfiddle?

Comment: fadeIn new page, fadeOut old page, just toggling the display to none or block will give you that sudden flicker.

Comment: I am loading content into the new page with ajax yes, and then switching pages after the content has been insterted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of toggling their `display` property stack all pages on top of each other and use z-index to show up the desired page:

```
.page {
    z-index: 1;
}

.page.current-page {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kRDnF/1/)**

Comment: this stops the flash, but position:absolute stops the page from scrolling?

Comment: depending on your DOM structure and CSS rules applied you may have to change some things. Perhaps the pages container its a good start. For example, when you give `position: absolute` to `.page` elements, its parent looses its height.

Comment: had to change quite alot of other css/ js for this to work, but now have no flicker between pages, wish i used this method from the start! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.current-page').toggleClass('current-page');
$('#'+desiredPage).hide().toggleClass('current-page').fadeIn();
```

Might be the sort of thing you're looking for?